# UIlabel height issue in Custom UItableViewCell in iOS 6 and iOS 7

Tags: ios7, uitableview, ios6, uilabel

i am displaying different items in custom table cell. when i try to display multiline uilabel text. it si only showing single line. even though i calculate the label height

also i try to set new frame with new height after calculation.

my code is as follows:

```
+(CGRect )getlabelHeight:(CGRect)frame withFontName:(NSString *)font andFontSize:(float)fontSize andText:(NSString *)text
```

{

CGSize constrainedSize = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, 9999);

```
NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      [UIFont fontWithName:font size:fontSize], NSFontAttributeName,
                                      nil];

NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:attributesDictionary];

CGRect requiredHeight = [string boundingRectWithSize:constrainedSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];

if (requiredHeight.size.width > constrainedSize.width) {
    requiredHeight = CGRectMake(0,0, constrainedSize.width, requiredHeight.size.height);
}
CGRect newFrame = frame;
newFrame.size.height = requiredHeight.size.height;
frame = newFrame;
return frame;
```

}

my tabelview method is as follows:

```
    CGRect descFrame=[Utility getlabelHeight:CGRectMake(65,35+titleFrame.size.height, 250, 20) withFontName:appFont andFontSize:15 andText:[[allComments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"comment"]];
NSLog(@"%@ \n %f",[[allComments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"comment"],descFrame.size.height);

[cell.title setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:appFont size:15]];
[cell.title setText:[[allComments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"comment"]];
[cell.title setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[cell.title setNumberOfLines:0];
[cell.title setFrame:descFrame];
[cell.title setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Please help me!!1 i am screwed...

thanks you!!!